# Plugging Downloaded Actionscript3 Into a Personal Project

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, action, flash-cs5.5

I'm a total beginner to all of this.

I'm trying to make a three-second bit in a flash animation (not a game or interface--just a small sequence which uses a parallax star field I found on freeactionscript.com:

http://www.freeactionscript.com/2010/06/endless-starfield-parallax-scrolling/

I'm simply wanting to plug this code into an existing project. I have been digging for hours to find *anything* on the subject of plugging in AS3 codes, but all I can find are items which presuppose an advanced understanding of ActionScript, and don't really relate to my issue to boot..

The error I keep getting is "1120: Access of undefined property parallaxField." I believe I've placed all the files in the proper file structure, but it still won't render.

I'm not even sure where to begin looking to fix it, how to define the 'parallaxField' property, or how to attach it to the project I'm working on.

Please let me know if there's any other information you need to help, if you can..

Much appreciated!

Comment: To be honest it's actually best to have at least a basic understanding of ActionScript before you start using other peoples' libraries or classes. Not only will you then know how to use them in a range of situations, but it'll also allow you to tweak them slightly if they don't fit your needs exactly. I can answer your question, but in all honestly it seems more fit for a general Flash forum than a programming Q&A site.

Comment: I have a decent knowledge of HTML and CSS and am able to manipulate certain items of appearance, etc., but beyond that.. I tried renaming the Main.as file to match the name of my project, I've tried changing the directories contained in the .as files, and I've tried copying the .as directly into the flash file itself as keyframe actionscript items, hoping the classes would simply become part of the project, itself, but no dice..

Comment: http://i69.photobucket.com/albums/i55/iyasu_yosomono/as_zpsc4a020e8.jpg

To show you the file names/structure. Everything in the com folder is the same as the original download, aside from some changes in direction, height/width, the key event handlers, and the star concentration..

Answer (score 0):

in that link there is a demo example to download,

you have to have the com folder with the subfolder and file it it place,

then in your main js file import that in the com folder

```
import com.freeactionscript.ParallaxField;
```

then define the variable inside your main class

```
private var parallaxField:ParallaxField;
```

then inside your constructor function

```
// create container for our parallax effect
var mainContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mainContainer);

// instantiate parallax class
parallaxField = new ParallaxField();

// createField(container, x, y, width, height, numberOfStars, speedX, speedY);
parallaxField.createField(mainContainer, 10, 10, 530, 380, 100, 1, 1.5);
```

Comment: That is how the code is already set up, yes. The .fla file that comes with it is simply a resource with the images utilized by the AS. The file structure is identical. The only difference is that the .fla is not named "Main." I tried renaming that, too, but it made no difference.

I'm simply trying to make these .AS files respond as is indicated by the developer of the script in a short segment of my animation project using his provided enable/disable codes as an on/off switch.

Comment: By the error code that you are getting semms that you did not defined the variable.  private var parallaxField:ParallaxField;

Comment: But where do I put that? Do I need to create a new .as file or do I write that directly into a keyframe in the animation? Part of my trouble is that I can't find out how to connect an outside actionscript file to the project in the first place..

Comment: just add the constructor part in the js file that you already have...   you have one don't you?